# How can i convert this into single string value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Max(Exam_Id)] => 6 ) ) 

public function get_max_exam_id()

{

 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT Max(Exam_Id) from exam_tb");
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Please explain your question more clearly, including your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add alias

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT Max(Exam_Id) as max_exam_id from exam_tb");
```

try to use row_array() instead result_array()

```
//return $query->result_array();
$result = $query->row_array();
return $result['max_exam_id'];
```

and access that with alias $result['max_exam_id']. maybe can help :)

Comment: your query gives this           Array ( [max_exam_id] => 6 ),  i want only 6 as output, please help.

Comment: just use before return $query->row_array(); to $result = $query->row_array(); and return $result['max_exam_id'];

Answer (score 0):

I have solved using following function `get_max_exam_id()`

```
public function get_max_exam_id()                                                                                         
{                                                                                    
   $this->db->select_max('Exam_Id');               
   $query = $this->db->get('exam_tb');
   $ret = $query->row();         
   return $ret->Exam_Id;
}
```